# How to register WebResource on the fly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources

Is it possible to register web resources on the fly?
I mean do this -

```
[assembly: WebResource("NameSpace.Resources.MyCSS.css", "text/css")]
```

I want to read resources' settings from my xml file. Content of these settings will contain necessary information to register a resource and will depend on what page is gonna be loaded.
So only those resources will be registered that the page really needs to use.

For example – one of my pages uses two images and one css file. I want to register them only, though I can have more images and css files as embedded resources in my project.
The reason to do this - not to register anything I don't need.

If it's possible, what benefits can it give to me in comparison with declaration every resource in AssemblyInfo.cs, for example?

Answer (score 0):

If you're determining which resources are needed dynamically, I'd think that would be more of an overhead than just declaring them all beforehand. You'd need to benchmark it, but to me, WebResources have never offered much of a benefit.